# Getting server error 400 while connecting server using cookie stored in browser JAVA

Tags: java

```
URL url = new URL("url");

URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

// conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
String mycookie = "value; JNAT=value; "
                + "LtpaToken2=value";

conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", mycookie);

conn.connect();
```

Comment: Thats because "url" is not a url

Comment: 1. "url" is not a URL as indicated by @shinjw. 2. Error 400 is `Bad request` meaning that there is something wrong with your request fromat.